# Python: typing, how to use an inner class from another inner class?

Tags: python, inner-classes, python-typing

Is it possible to specify a parameter of an inner class function as being types as another inner class?

```
class MyClass():
    
    class InnerClass1():
        pass
        
    class InnerClass2():
        def func(self, param: InnerClass1):
            pass
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyClass()
```

This reports `NameError: name 'InnerClass1' is not defined`

Using `param: MyClass.InnerClass1` reports `NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined`

If this is not possible, what could be the alternative to correctly declare parameter type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class) (dupe, since you actually still need to refer to the enclosing class, and there are better answers)

Comment: @STerliakov: Yes it does, even if John's answer is just perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the type by string:

```py
class MyClass():
    
    class InnerClass1():

        @property
        def name(self) -> str:
            return "name"
        
    class InnerClass2():
        def func(self, param: "MyClass.InnerClass1"):
            pass
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyClass()
```

This shows VS Code autocomplete working for `param`:

[image: VS Code autocomplete for property of an inner class]