# How do I define a class in Python to say that that class can have an instance of itself as a child

Tags: python, class, type-hinting

How do I define a base class in Python, with type hinting, to say that that class can have an instance of itself as a attribute.

For example.....

```
class Person():
    first_name: str = None
    last_name: str = None
    parent: Person = None

    def __init__(self, first_name: str = None, last_name: str = None, parent: Person = None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.parent = parent
```

I get an error about the class no existing if I try to type hint that class in the class.
Seems like a really simple solution but I feel really dumb.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends on the version of Python you're using. If you're on 3.11 or newer, [you can use `Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) instead of the class name. If not, peruse that ["How do I type hint a method with the type of the enclosing class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class) post.

Comment: Important detail: using `Self` and `'Person'` are not exactly equivalent when it comes to subclasses. `Self` refers to the current class, so if you used `Self` as an annotation and then have `class Employee(Person)`, `Employee`s can only have `Employee`s as parents, not `Person`s who are not `Employee`s. This may be what you want or it may not be.

Comment: Terminology note: this is not what "child" means in this context.  Take care to use terminology correctly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, good catch.....yea i guess since I said base class child could probably mean the inheriting class. I corrected it to say as an attribute of the class.