Python annotate adding class members in __get__
I want to create a decorator that adds a member to the decorated class
that is instance of outer class.
In this case, decorator memberclass adds attribute self to the instance of class y that is of type X
class memberclass[Y]:
    def __init__(self, cls: type[Y]):
        self.cls = cls

    def __get__(self, x, cls) -> Y | type[Y]:
        if x is None: return self.cls
        # I deleted some lines related to memorizing y per instance of X
        y = self.cls()
        y.self = x
        return y


class X:
    z: int
    @memberclass
    class y:
        def f(self):
            # self.self is instace of X
            # type checker should be aware of self.self.z


# X.y is class y
# X().y is instance of that class
# X().y.self is X()

My best guess would be that there might be some way
to annotate __get__ method to say "Y is getting a new member self with type typeof x".

I checked whole documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html and didn't find solution.
This also didn't help How to type hint python magic __get__ method since it doesn't show how to modify type
This also didn't help Is it possible to change method type annotations for a class instance? since it modifies function signature, but not the class members

The X class doesn't exist when @memberclass is called. The class isn't defined until after the end of the class X: block.

Note also that adding self: X to class y would work, but is redundant

Nested classes are rarely useful in Python.

@Barmar this is not a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class

X.y is not the class; it's an instance of memberclass that has a reference to y.

@chepner in this specific situation X.y would actually return the actual class. But that is not important here.

True, I was thinking of X.__dict__['y'], not the attribute lookup.

You can’t statically add attributes to a class using a decorator; that requires intersection types, which isn’t developed in Python yet.
